# how to get email of facebook during login process

Tags: asp.net, facebook-graph-api

```
 FaceBookConnect.API_Key = <>;
 FaceBookConnect.API_Secret = <>;
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            if (Request.QueryString["error"] == "access_denied")
            {
                ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('User has denied access.')", true);
                return;
            }

        string code = Request.QueryString["code"];
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(code))
        {
            string data = FaceBookConnect.Fetch(code, "me");
            FaceBookUser faceBookUser = new   JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<FaceBookUser>(data);
            faceBookUser.PictureUrl = string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/{0}/picture", faceBookUser.Id);
            lblId.Text = faceBookUser.Id;
            lblUserName.Text = faceBookUser.UserName;
            lblName.Text = faceBookUser.Name;
            lblEmail.Text = faceBookUser.Email;
            ProfileImage.ImageUrl = faceBookUser.PictureUrl;
```

Answer (score 0):

> > The Graph API is the primary way to get data in and out of Facebook's social graph. It's a low-level HTTP-based API that you can use to query data, post new stories, upload photos and a variety of other tasks that an app might need to do

So you are using Graph API here but for that you need permission from the user you intend to read data. For permission

```
FaceBookConnect.Authorize("about,email", Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
```

Helpful Links:

1. http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-Get-FaceBook-User-details-like-Gender-Email-Address-Location-and-Birth-Date.aspx
2. https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/

Comment: when i write string data = FaceBookConnect.Fetch(code, "mefields=about,email");                                                                                  i am getting errorThe remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

Comment: @ShamsAgaz can you check edits and I have also added links that might be helpful for you